# JavaScript event listener that fires when I hit enter on the input element on webpages

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I am very new to JavaScript. I am trying to figure out when the user hits enter on an input element in a web page(Google search bar in [www.google.com](http://www.google.com), for example). So far, I have tried the following code:

```
document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('keypress', function (e) {
    if (e.key === 'Enter') {
        console.log('Enter pressed');
    }
});
```

But this does not seem to work. I am sure I am doing something wrong. Can somebody help me with this?

UPDATE: I am trying to fetch the input elements without using their input id's.

Comment: usually we use `keyup`

Comment: @Ifaruki but that doesn't make a difference in this case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to attach the event listener to all the input elements in the page even for the dynamically created ones, then you need to use event delegation and in this case for the body element, since it will always be present, here is a simple solution:

```js
document.body.addEventListener('keypress', function(e) {
  // check if the element is an `input` element and the key is `enter`
  if(e.target.nodeName === "INPUT" && e.key === 'Enter') {
    console.log('Enter pressed and the value is: ' + e.target.value);
  }
});
```

```css
input {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 2px ridge lightgreen;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  box-shadow: -2px -2px 5px rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.7);
}
```

```html
<!-- values for testing -->
<input type="text" value="text 1">
<input type="text" value="text 15">
<input type="text" value="text 6">
<input type="text" value="text 24">
<input type="text">
<input type="text" value="text 3">
<input type="text" value="text 35">
```

Comment: This works fine when I hit enter on the google search bar. But I triehitting enter on an auto complete option and the logic was not working then. Is it possible to include that scenario as well?

Comment: Can you pls point me to that webpage so I can see its inner implementation

Comment: I am looking to use this on multiple webpages like google.com, duckduckgo.com and such

Comment: I saw there is a fuction to submit forms as well. Is it possible to submit forms without the form id. That might solve this issue since that will be called irrespective of the user hitting enter on the search bar or the autocomplete option. I asked a separate question on this here -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64927776/eventlistener-for-submit-form-irrespective-of-form-id-in-javascript?noredirect=1#comment114790319_64927776

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the `eventListener` to `keyup`

```js
document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('keyup', function (e) {
  console.log(e)
    if (e.key === 'Enter') {
        console.log('Enter pressed');
    }
});
```

```html
<input type="text"/>
```

Comment: This works when I use 'body' instead of input in document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('keyup', function (e). But when i use 'input', it does not work. Is 'input' wrong? I am trying to target all the input elements.

Comment: What is your input element HTML looks like?

Comment: I don't have any input html that I am creating. I am trying to access the elements from websites like google. For example, if I hit enter on the google search bar on www.google.com, i want the eventlistener to recognise it.

Comment: You can create a chrome extension and capture the values with it

Answer (score 0):

```js
inp.addEventListener('keypress', function (e) {
    if (e.code === "Enter") {
       numb.innerHTML = +numb.innerHTML + 1;
    }
});
```

```html
<input id="inp">
<p id="numb">0</p>
```

Comment: <input id="inp">
<p id="numb">0</p> Where do I insert these lines?

Comment: @onetrueshady this is html