# EventListener for submit form irrespective of form id in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

Is there any way to add an eventlistener that will run whenever any of the forms in the webpage gets submitted? This need to run on all the websites, for example, on [www.google.com](http://www.google.com), whenever the user searches something, the eventlistener should run.

I am not using any html file. So it is not possible to use the form id.

I am a Swift developer but need to use JavaScript in this scenario. So really need some help here.

Note: There is a similar question on StackOverflow, but that is for Ajax. I am looking to use only JavaScript.

UPDATE: I need an eventlistener that will get executed whenever a user searches something on any search engine website, like google, bing, etc. The eventlistener should run when the users 1. hits enter on the search box. 2. clicks on the search button. 3. clicks on or hits enter on the autocomplete search predictions.

as of now I am able to achieve 1 and 2 using the following code:

```
document.body.addEventListener('keypress', function(e) {
  // check if the element is an `input` element and the key is `enter`
  if((e.target.nodeName === "INPUT") && e.key === 'Enter') {
    console.log('Enter pressed Input');
  }
});
document.body.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if(e.target.nodeName === "INPUT") {
    console.log('Clicked Input');
  }
});
document.body.addEventListener('keypress', function(e) {
  if(e.target.nodeName === "DIV" && e.key === 'Enter') {
    console.log('Enter pressed in Autocomplete');
  }
});
document.body.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if(e.target.nodeName === "LI") {
    console.log('Clicked Autocomplete');
  }
});
```

However, I am not able to achieve target 3 yet.
I thought maybe if I was able to implement an eventlistener that would run whenever the form gets submitted, all the three targets will be achieved. I am not sure as I am new to JavaScript.

I also need to do it without using any form id as the same code needs to be compatible with multiple forms.

I hope this makes it clearer now.

Comment: It's really not clear what the question is here. Are you asking about any form in a web page you are writing or in all web pages visited by the user anywhere on the WWW? Where is your JS running — in a `<script>` element? Somewhere else?

Comment: "There is a similar question on StackOverflow, but that is for Ajax. I am looking to use only JavaScript." — Ajax is a buzzword meaning "Make an HTTP request using JavaScript". It has nothing to do with adding event listeners.

Comment: According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit_event), submit event bubbles, and it can be listened on an ancestor parent element.

Comment: I updated the question. Hopefully its clearer now.

Answer (score 0):

Well then you don't need to listen for the key press, instead listen for the submit event, using event delegation, here is a solution, note that we're getting the value of the input with the name `"q"` cause most of the search engines use it as a name for the search input:

```js
document.body.addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
  // prevent the form submitting
  e.preventDefault();
  // clear the console from old messages
  console.clear();
  // output the serached text
  console.log(e.target.querySelector("[name='q']").value);
  // after 3 seconds submit the form (just for demonstration)
  setTimeout(function() {
    e.target.submit();
  }, 3000);
});
```

```html
<form action="https://duckduckgo.com/">
<input type="text" name="q">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: This is not working on google.com. Also, in duckduckgo, its working for most of the conditions except when i click on any of the autocomplete suggestions. It, however, is working when i hit enter on the autocomplete options.

Comment: For more clarity, I have posted another question elaborating the situation -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64963546/javascript-proper-implementation-of-submit