# JavaScript proper implementation of submit

Tags: javascript

I am very new to JavaScript. I am trying to have a functionality where I get to know whenever a user searches on websites like google.com or duckduckgo.com. There are four scenarios where this needs to work-

1. When the users hits enter on the search bar.
2. When the user clicks on the search button.
3. When the user hits enter on an autocomplete search suggestion.
4. When the user clicks on an autocomplete search suggestion.

I have the following code:

```
document.body.addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
console.log('About to submit')
e.target.submit()
}
```

This code works partially on duckduckgo.com (It works on scenarios 1, 2 and 3. But does not work on scenario 4). Also, this code does not work at all on google.com.

I am only starting with JavaScript. I am sure I am missing something. Can anybody help me with this?

UPDATE: Is it possible to implement it without using any form id as I would like the code to work in scenarios with multiple forms as well.

Answer (score 1):

1. You need to handle the form submit on enter and click on submit using the submit event
2. For autocomplete, you need to remove the autocomplete handler from the form and add change handler

**Duck**

```js
const form = document.querySelector("form"); // first form on page

const submitting = (form,e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log('About to submit')
  form.submit()
};


form.addEventListener("change",e => submitting(form,e))
form.addEventListener("submit",e => submitting(form,e))
```

```html
<form id="search_form_homepage" class="search--home  js-search-form search--adv" name="x" method="GET" action="https://duckduckgo.com/">
  <input id="search_form_input_homepage" class="js-search-input search__input--adv" type="text" Xautocomplete="off" name="q" tabindex="1" value="" autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off" placeholder="Search the web without being tracked">
  <input id="search_button_homepage" class="search__button  js-search-button" type="submit" tabindex="2" value="S">
  <input id="search_form_input_clear" class="search__clear  empty  js-search-clear" type="button" tabindex="3" value="X">
  <div id="search_elements_hidden" class="search__hidden  js-search-hidden"><input type="hidden" class="js-search-hidden-field" name="va" value="b"><input type="hidden" class="js-search-hidden-field" name="t" value="hc"></div>
  <div class="search__autocomplete" style="display: none;">
    <div class="acp-wrap js-acp-wrap"></div>
    <div class="acp-footer is-hidden js-acp-footer"><span class="acp-footer__instructions">Shortcuts to other sites to search off DuckDuckGo</span><span class="acp-footer__link"><a class="no-visited js-acp-footer-link" href="/bang">Learn More</a></span></div>
  </div>
</form>
```

**Google**

```js
const form = document.querySelector("form"); // first form on page

const submitting = (form, e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log('About to submit')
  form.submit()
};


form.addEventListener("change", e => submitting(form, e))
form.addEventListener("submit", e => submitting(form, e))
```

```html
<form action="https://google.com/search" method="GET" id="search_form">
  <input type="text" name="q" />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

More than one form:

```js
const submitting = (form, e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log('About to submit')
  form.submit()
};


window.addEventListener("load", () => {
  document.body.addEventListener("submit", e => {
    submitting(e.target, e)
  });
  document.body.addEventListener("change", e => {
    submitting(e.target.closest("form"), e)
  })
})
```

```html
<form id="search_form_homepage" class="search--home  js-search-form search--adv" name="x" method="GET" action="https://duckduckgo.com/">
  <input id="search_form_input_homepage" class="js-search-input search__input--adv" type="text" Xautocomplete="off" name="q" tabindex="1" value="" autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off" placeholder="Search the web without being tracked">
  <input id="search_button_homepage" class="search__button  js-search-button" type="submit" tabindex="2" value="S">
  <input id="search_form_input_clear" class="search__clear  empty  js-search-clear" type="button" tabindex="3" value="X">
  <div id="search_elements_hidden" class="search__hidden  js-search-hidden"><input type="hidden" class="js-search-hidden-field" name="va" value="b"><input type="hidden" class="js-search-hidden-field" name="t" value="hc"></div>
  <div class="search__autocomplete" style="display: none;">
    <div class="acp-wrap js-acp-wrap"></div>
    <div class="acp-footer is-hidden js-acp-footer"><span class="acp-footer__instructions">Shortcuts to other sites to search off DuckDuckGo</span><span class="acp-footer__link"><a class="no-visited js-acp-footer-link" href="/bang">Learn More</a></span></div>
  </div>
</form>


<form action="https://google.com/search" method="GET" id="search_form">
  <input type="text" name="q" />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Is it possible to do it without using an html file?

Comment: I do not understand what you mean.

Comment: You can use a JavaScript file that renders the form, but that will have to live in an html file too. I added google for you

Comment: Is it possible without the form id? I would also like the code to work on websites with multiple forms.

Comment: I changed the code to not use an ID and added code that can handle more than one form